# Am I handling Hibernate Sessions correctly?

Tags: java, hibernate, session

I am working on converting a code base that uses one single `Session` instance variable, initially obtained by using `getCurrentSession()`, for all of the database communication to a thread safe environment. I understand why this is a thread safe risk. To make the code base thread safe, I removed the instance variable and just opened and closed a session per each "unit of work". Example:

```
private void updateEntity(DataEntity dataEntity)
{
    Session session = SessionFactoryUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    try
    {
        session.update(dataEntity);
        transaction.commit();
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e)
    {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
    finally
    {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

My understanding is that a session obtained by `getCurrentSession()` is automatically closed after the transaction is committed. I also proved this via debugging. Is this correct way to use `getCurrentSession()`? Is this thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

You need thread safety for the session AND every single entity associated with that session.

For instance if you use the session in Thread X to load an entity and use that entity in Thread Y, then it won't be thread safe.
The reason is that the entity might have references to the session. For instance it might have a lazy collection that needs to hit the session to initialize. Since the initialization might happen in Thread Y you are effectively using the session from two threads.

Comment: Is making every single entity "thread safe" a design implementation or is it something that you can leverage hibernate to do for you?

Comment: If entities A and B are associated with a session you cannot access them from different threads. So even if they are thread safe the limitation is on the entire graph of entities associated with the Session